# Non-covalent interactions

Tags: intermolecular-forces

According to Keesom, Debye and London effect, the non-covalent reactions should be stronger, the bigger are electric charge differences between two interacting particles. E.g. Ion-induced dipole are stronger than dipole-induced dipole interactions.

So shouldn't be Van der Waals forces stronger than hydrophobic interactions? It is said that if we count with greater amounts of a substance, the hydrophobic interactions can be even stronger than hydrogen bonds. But aren't hydrophobic powers actually composed of the above mentioned effects? If two particles were absolutely neutral, they would not react since only opposite characteristics are attracted towards each other. These weak opposite charges can be caused also in non-polar substances by London effect. But that effect should be weaker than Keesom effect between permanent dipoles which contribute to VDW forces, for example in water.

Is it true that Van der Waals forces are stronger than hydrophobic interactions?